# /usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-32-generic' arch/x86/Makefile:147: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support

Tags: kernel, compiling, gcc, make

please help, i make a file named hello.c

```
#include linux/module.h
#include linux/kernel.h
#include linux/init.h

static int __init hello_start(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading hello module...\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world Mr. Praktikan\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_end(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye Mr. Praktikan\n");
}

module_init(hello_start);
module_exit(hello_end);
```

then i make Makefile

```
obj-m = hello.o
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

but when i run it with 'make', it shows some errors

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.0.0-32-generic/build M=/home/nisrina/Documents/Bab 2 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-32-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:147: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '2'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-32-generic'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

what should i do?:(

Comment: First thing I would do is rename the directory `M=/home/nisrina/Documents/Bab 2` to one without spaces (that's why you're getting an error about `No rule to make target '2'`

Comment: it works! thank you steeldriver!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem just now.

Remove the spaces from your build path.

make -C /lib/modules/5.0.0-32-generic/build M=/home/nisrina/Documents/**Bab 2 modules**

**should be**

make -C /lib/modules/5.0.0-32-generic/build M=/home/nisrina/Documents/Bab_2_modules

I know this sounds like a silly fix , but it worked for me.